# Integral of Gamma Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, special-functions

Is the following integral able to be expressed by closed form or special functions?

$$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(at+b)}{\Gamma(ct+b)}\right)\frac{dt}{t}$$, for any non-negative numbers $a,b,c$. As I know Raabe's integral can be actually evaluated. (See [Raabe's integral for complex argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276592/raabes-integral-for-complex-argument)) I originally guess that this integral can be related to Raabe's integral.

Appreciate!

Comment: The same question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292266/integral-of-gamma-functions/292267#comment725069_292267)

Comment: It boils down to $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\Gamma(at+b)}{t}\,dt$ (hence the $c$-parameter is irrelevant), or to $\int_{0}^{a}\frac{\log\Gamma(t+b)}{t}\,dt $, or to $\int_{0}^{a} \psi(t+b)\log(t)\,dt$ by integration by parts. This is related to $\text{Li}_2$ via $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}$ and $\int_{0}^{1} x^n \log(x)\,dx = -\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$.

Comment: I am wondering if $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\Gamma(at+b)}{t}dt$$ converges when we consider as $t$ approaches to $0$.