# Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x)\ln(1-x)\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, problem-solving

Evaluate the integral,

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x)\ln(1-x)\,dx$$

I solved this problem, by writing power series and then calculating the series and found the answer to be $ 2 -\zeta(2) $, **but I don't think that it is best solution to this problem.**   I want to know if it can be solved by any other *nice/elegant method.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Integrating by parts,

$$ \int \ln(x) \ln(1-x) \, dx = x \ln(x) \ln(1-x) - x \ln(1-x)+ \int \frac{x \ln (x)}{1-x} \, dx - \int \frac{x}{1-x} \, dx$$

where

$$  \int \frac{x}{1-x} \, dx = - \int \ dx + \int \frac{1}{1-x} \, dx = -x - \ln(1-x) + C_{1}$$

and $$ \begin{align} \int \frac{x \ln (x)}{1-x} \, dx &= -x \ln (x) - \ln(x) \ln(1-x) + \int dx + \int \frac{\ln (1-x)}{x} \, dx  \\  &= -x \ln (x) - \ln(x) \ln(1-x) + x - \text{Li}_{2}(x) + C_{2}. \end{align}$$

$\text{Li}_{2}(x)$ is the [dilogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm).

So we have $$ \begin{align} \int \ln(x) \ln(1-x) \, dx &= x \ln(x) \ln(1-x) - x \ln(1-x) - x \ln(x) - \ln(x) \ln(1-x) + 2x  \\ &- \text{Li}_{2}(x) + \ln(1-x) + C . \end{align} $$

Therefore,

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x) \ln(1-x) \ dx = \lim_{x \to 1} \left[-x \ln(1-x)+\ln(1-x) \right] + 2 - \text{Li}_{2}(1) = 2 - \zeta(2) .$$

Comment: I also tried this, but it turns out too lengthy. +1 as usual.

Comment: Thanks for your compliment but I think that's too much, rather your answers and sos440 are very impressive either at MSE or I&S, you both never ceases to amaze me. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey, so you are a user in I&S!

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai No, I am not, maybe one day I'll join there. For the time being, I only participate in here and Brilliant.org. I only visit and observe I&S as a non-member. Anyway, I also enjoy your posts in I&S especially for the series and integral involving polylog.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey What is I&S?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland A&Q site like MSE but it's specialized for [Integral and Series](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com) problems.

Answer (score 20):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\ln(1-x)\ln x\ dx&=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n\ln x\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}n\int_0^1 x^n\ln x\ dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}n\cdot\frac1{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}n-\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}\right]\\
&=1-\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}-1\right]\\
&=\large\color{blue}{2-\zeta(2)=2-\frac{\pi^2}6}.
\end{align}

---

**Note :**

[$\displaystyle\ \ \int_0^1 x^\alpha \ln^n x\ dx=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(\alpha+1)^{n+1}}, \qquad\text{for }\  n=0,1,2,\ldots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/905818/123277)

Comment: Ups, I didn't see the OP. I'll edit it if an idea comes to mind. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @JackD'Aurizio. Unfortunately, this is not what OP wants, he asked for other methods. Anyway, have you found a way to obtain the problem asked by V-Moy: a closed-form for $$\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln^2\cos x\ dx\ ?$$I tried to answer but without success so far.

Comment: The line below (608) in http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse13.php#x15-12200013 was the key: Landen identities give that the value of such an integral depends on $\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)$ as "claimed" by Mathematica.

Comment: $\zeta(2)$ might not look to significant to the OP. Add the fact that it is $\frac{\pi^2}6$

Answer (score 10):

Using the reflection formula

$$\log(x)\log(1-x) =\zeta(2)-\mathrm{Li}_2(x)-\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x)  $$

\begin{align}
\int^1_0\log(x)\log(1-x) &=\zeta(2)-\int^1_0\mathrm{Li}_2(x)\,dx-\int^1_0\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x)\,dx\\ &=\zeta(2)-2\int^1_0\mathrm{Li}_2(x)\,dx\\
&=\zeta(2)-2\zeta(2)-2\int^1_0\log(1-x)\,dx\\
&=2-\zeta(2)
\end{align}

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ 1}\ln\pars{1 - x}\dd\bracks{x\ln\pars{x} - x + 1}
> \\[3mm]&=\left.\bracks{x\ln\pars{x} - x + 1}\ln\pars{1 - x}\right\vert_{0}^{1}
> -\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{x\ln\pars{x} - x + 1}\,{-1 \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> =\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x + 1
> \\[3mm]&=-\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 1}\partiald{}{\mu}
> \int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x + 1
> =-\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 1}\partiald{\Psi\pars{\mu + 1}}{\mu} + 1
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm)
>   $\ds{\bf 6.3.1}$ and we used the [identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) $\ds{\bf 6.3.22}$.

$$
\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x}
=-\Psi'\pars{2} + 1=-\Psi'\pars{1} + 2=-\zeta\pars{2} + 2
$$
Here we used the identities:
$$
\Psi'\pars{z + 1} = \Psi'\pars{z} - {1 \over z^{2}}\,,\qquad
\Psi^{\rm\pars{n}}\pars{1}=\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,n!\,\zeta\pars{n + 1}\,,\quad n = 1,2,3,\ldots
$$

> Since $\ds{\zeta\pars{2} = {\pi^{2} \over 6}}$:
>   $$
> \color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x}
> =\color{#66f}{\large 2 - {\pi^{2} \over 6}} \approx {\tt 0.3551}
> $$

Comment: i love your answers!+1

Comment: @ADG Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You could start from the Beta function
$$ B(p+1,r+1) = \int_0^1 x^p (1-x)^r\; dx = \dfrac{\Gamma(p+1) \Gamma(r+1)}{\Gamma(p+r+2)}$$
take the derivatives with respect to $p$ and $r$, and evaluate at
$p=r=0$.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution that is interesting, but probably not elegant, and definitely not short.

$I = \displaystyle\int_0^1 \ln(x)\ln(1 - x) dx$

**Basic results:**

- $\lim\limits_{n \to 0} \dfrac{x^n - 1}{n} = \log x$, or $\lim\limits_{n \to 1}\dfrac{x^{n-1} - 1}{n - 1} = \log x$.
- $\dfrac{d}{dn}\beta(n, n) = 2\beta(n, n)(\psi_0(n) - \psi_0(2n))$ where $\psi_0(n)$ is the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html).
- $\dfrac{d^2}{dn^2}\beta(n, n) = 4\beta(n, n)(\psi_0(n) - \psi_0(2n))^2 + 2\beta(n, n)(\psi_1(n) - 2\psi_1(2n))$, where $\psi(1)(n)$ is the [polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html).
- $\psi_0(1) - \psi_0(2) = -1$ according to the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization).
- $\psi_1(2) = \psi_1(1) - 1$ according to the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Recurrence_relation).
- $\psi_1(1) = \zeta(2)$.

**Solution:**
$\begin{align}
I & = \lim\limits_{n \to 1} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{(x^{n - 1} - 1)((1 - x)^{n - 1} - 1)}{(n - 1)^2} dx\\
& = \lim\limits_{n \to 1}\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n-1} - x^{n - 1} - (1-x)^{n-1} + 1}{(n-1)^2} dx\\
& = \lim\limits_{n \to 1} \dfrac{\beta(n,n) - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n} + 1}{(n-1)^2}\\
& = \lim\limits_{n \to 1} \dfrac{\beta(n,n)(\psi_0(n)-\psi_0(2n)) + \frac{2}{n^2}}{2(n-1)} \quad [\text{l'Hospital's rule}]\\
& = \lim\limits_{n \to 1} \dfrac{4\beta(n,n)(\psi_0(n)-\psi_0(2n))^2 + 2\beta(n,n)(\psi_1(n)-2\psi_1(2n))- \frac{4}{n^3}}{2}\quad [\text{l'Hospital's rule}]\\
& = 2\beta(1, 1)(\psi_0(1) - \psi_0(2))^2 + \beta(1, 1)(\psi_1(1) - 2\psi_1(2)) - 2\\
& = 2(-1)^2 + 1(\psi_1(1) - 2\psi_1(1) + 2) - 2\\
& = 2 - \psi_1(1)\\
& = 2-\zeta(2)
\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

You could expand
$\ln(1-x)
=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}
$
and evaluate
$\int_0^1  x^n \ln x\,dx$,
probably by an induction
via integration by parts.

From your description,
you may have already done this.

It sure is easier to 
write this than to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Noting
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[x(1-\ln(1-x))+\ln(1-x)]=-\ln(1-x) $$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1\ln x\ln(1-x)dx&=&-\int_0^1\ln xd[x(1-\ln(1-x))+\ln(1-x)]\\
&=&-[x(1-\ln(1-x))+\ln(1-x)]\ln x\bigg|_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{x(1-\ln(1-x))+\ln(1-x)}{x}dx\\
&=&\int_0^1(1-\ln(1-x)+\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x})dx\\
&=&\int_0^1(1-\ln(1-x))dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx\\
&=&2-\zeta(2).
\end{eqnarray}
Here we used the well-known result 
$$ \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=-\zeta(2). $$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts

\begin{align}
 \int_{0}^{1} \ln x\ln(1-x)\,dx
= -2\int_0^1 \ln xdx +\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx
=2-\zeta(2)
\end{align}