# Integral $\int_0^1 \ln x \ln(1-x)d x$

Tags: integration

How can I prove that
$$\int_{0}^{1} \ln x \ln(1-x)dx = 2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

I could not find an antiderivative for $f(x)=\ln x  \ln(1-x)$. I was thinking to add a parameter but did not see
a useful place where to add it. Any further suggestions?

Comment: It's a duplicate of [Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x)\ln(1-x)\,dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917833/evaluate-int-01-lnx-ln1-x-dx). See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1414022/515527

Comment: @Nyssa - oh thank you, I was looking for this