# Definite integral of $\ln(x) \ln(1-x)$ from $x= 0$ to $1$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Evaluate  $$\int_{0}^{1} \ln (x) \ln(1-x) dx$$

Comment: Two line questions are frowned upon...

Comment: the result should be $$2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove," "Evaluate," etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: If I may suggest, just **ignore** any answer or comment which gives the result without any explanation. **Anyone** is able to use a CAS. I suppose that you want to learn.

Comment: Learning to use a CAS is even better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x)\ln(1-x)\,dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917833/evaluate-int-01-lnx-ln1-x-dx)

Answer (score 8):

$$\int_0^1 \ln(x) \ln(1-x) dx = -\int_0^1 \ln(x) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} dx \\
=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^1 x^n  \ln(x) dx $$
So, let $I_n = \int_0^1 x^n \ln(x) dx$.  Using integration by parts, we see $I_n = -\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, so
$$\int_0^1 \ln(x) \ln(1-x) dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)^2} \\
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)n^2} \\
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2} \\
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}\right)- \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} \\
= \frac{1}{2-1} - \left(\frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1\right) \\
= 2 - \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\$$

Comment: You probably should justify why you are allowed to swap $\sum_1^\infty$ and $\int_0^1$ in your second step. This is not always possible.

Comment: This is a good point.