# Evaluating $\int_0^1 (\ln(x)\ln(1-x))^n dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

Interested in evaluating:

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 (\ln(x)\ln(1-x))^n \mathrm{d}x,$ where $n \in \Bbb Z^+.$

I don't really know how to tackle this problem for $n > 1.$

I was able to get to this step: $\displaystyle\int_0^1 (\ln(x)\ln(1-x))^n \mathrm{d}x= \int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n\ln x\right)^n \mathrm{d}x$.

This question is related to:
[Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x)\ln(1-x)\,dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917833/evaluate-int-01-lnx-ln1-x-dx)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: u-substitution and integration by parts

Comment: Why don't you use the beta function? (take some derivates).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$$
Where $B(x,y)$ is the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). Thus $$\int_0^1 \left(\ln(t)\ln(1-t)\right)^ndt=\left(\frac{d}{dy}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^nB(x,y)|_{(x,y)=(1,1)}$$

Comment: I love this method. Nice work (+1)

Comment: Note that for actual computation, one should look at the log derivative.

Comment: Came here to post this! you beat me to it! :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt - Won't that fall apart with it being the nth derivative? It seems it will be a nightmarish mess no matter what approach is taken.

Comment: @aleden - Not to critique your work - but for anyone reading, the ability to use this identity relies on the Beta Function's Integrand complying with both the Dominated Convergence Theorem and Leibniz's Integral Rule. [

Comment: @DavidG seems to be the nicest place to start, but yeah, it'll still be messy.