# Find $\int _0^1\frac{12\arctan ^2 x\ln (\frac{(1-x)^2}{1+x^2})-\ln ^3(\frac{(1-x)^2}{1+x^2})}{x}\:dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, trigonometric-integrals

I want to find and prove that: $$\int _0^1\frac{12\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(\frac{\left(1-x\right)^2}{1+x^2}\right)-\ln ^3\left(\frac{\left(1-x\right)^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{x}\:dx=\frac{9 \pi ^4}{16}$$
I tried to split the integral:
$$=12\int _0^1\frac{\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(\frac{\left(1-x\right)^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{x}\:dx+12\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{x}\:dx$$
$$-6\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln ^2\left(1+x^2\right)}{x}\:dx+\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^3\left(1+x^2\right)}{x}\:dx-8\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^3\left(1-x\right)}{x}\:dx$$
But the first $3$ integrals are very tough, expanding some terms yield very complicated series.
I also attempted to integrate by parts but it was rather messy and I'd prefer not to put it here. I have faith that there must be a trick for finding this one because of its closed forms simplicity.

Note $2$: I found this integral in a certain mathematics group, I've ask for hints but received none.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Integrals of such form (i.e. combination of $\arctan x, \log x, \log(1\pm x), \log(1+x^2$)) have [systematic way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763243) of calculation. If you randomly write down such an integral, there is likely no slick way.

However, for this particular one, there is something behind. Writing $a=\arctan x, b=\log(\frac{(1-x)^2}{1+x^2})$, I will simultaneously prove OP's question as well as the following generalizations
$$\begin{aligned}I_3 &= \color{red}{\int_0^1 \frac{12a^2b-b^3}{x} dx = \frac{9\pi^4}{16}} \\
I_5 &= \int_0^1 \frac{-80 a^4 b+40 a^2 b^3-b^5}{x} dx = \frac{33 \pi ^6}{8} \\
I_7 &= \int_0^1 \frac{448 a^6 b-560 a^4 b^3+84 a^2 b^5-b^7}{x} dx = \frac{2193 \pi ^8}{32} \end{aligned}$$

Here numerator of $I_n$ is real part of $(2ai-b)^n$. Write
$$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{\Re[(2ai-b)^n]}{x}dx = -2^n \int_0^1 \frac{\Re[(\log(1-x)-\log(1+ix))^n]}{x}dx $$
then for $n$ odd, $\frac{I_n}{\pi^{n+1}} \in \mathbb{Q}$. More precisely, if $n=2m+1$,

> $$\tag{*}I_n = 2^{2n-2}3\pi^{n+1}(-1)^{m+1} \sum_{r=0}^m \binom{n}{2r+1}
> \left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^{2r}
> \frac{1}{n-2r}B_{n-2r}\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)$$

here $B_n(x)$ is Bernoulli polynomial, from which above cited values of $I_n$ follows.

---

*Proof of $(*)$:*
Integrate $\frac{(\log(1-z)-\log(1+iz))^n}{z}$ around quarter circle in the first quadrant, the integral from $0$ to $i$ is
$$\begin{aligned}2^n \int_0^i \frac{(\log(1-x)-\log(1+ix))^n}{x}dx &= 2^n \int_0^1 \frac{(\log(1-ix)-\log(1-x))^n}{x}dx \\
&= -2^n \int_0^1 \frac{(\log(1-x)-\log(1-ix))^n}{x}dx \end{aligned}$$
so the real part of $\int_0^i$ is $-I_n$. Hence, if $C$ is the quarter circle,
$$\begin{aligned} 2I_n &= 2^n\Re \int_C \frac{(\log(1-z)-\log(1+iz))^n}{z}dz \\
&= -2^n\Im \int_0^{\pi/2} (\log(1-e^{ix})-\log(1+ie^{ix}))^n dx 
\end{aligned}$$
Now $$\log(1-e^{ix})-\log(1+ie^{ix}) = \log\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)}{\sin(\pi/4-x/2)}\right)-\frac{3i\pi}{4}$$
Hence if we write $n=2m+1$,
$$I_n = 2^n \sum_{r=0}^m \binom{2m+1}{2r+1} (-1)^r\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)^{2r+1}\int_0^{\pi/4} \log^{2(m-r)}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sin(\pi/4-x)}\right) dx$$
As a [lesser known fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2932348), integrals like those in the summand are always rational multiple of $\pi^{2(m-r)+1}$:
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\log^{2n}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sin(\pi/4-x)}\right) dx = \pi^{2n+1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n+1}}{2n+1}B_{2n+1}\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)$$
QED.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an answer.*

I had a look at
$$\int _0^1\frac{\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\log \left(\frac{\left(1-x\right)^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{x}\,dx$$ and used
$$\log \left(\frac{\left(1-x\right)^2}{1+x^2}\right)=-4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{  \sin ^2\left(\frac{n\pi  }{4}\right)}{n}\,x^n$$ I have not been able to compute
$$I_n=\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\,\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\,dx$$ for general $n$ but they look interesting
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & I_n \\
 1 & -C+\frac{\pi ^2}{16}+\frac{1}{4} \pi  \log (2) \\
 2 & -\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{\pi ^2}{16}+\frac{\log (2)}{2} \\
 3 & \frac{1}{3}+\frac{C}{3}-\frac{\pi }{6}+\frac{\pi ^2}{48}-\frac{1}{12} \pi  \log
   (2) \\
 4 & \frac{1}{12}+\frac{\pi }{12}-\frac{\log (2)}{3} \\
 5 & -\frac{4}{15}-\frac{C}{5}+\frac{\pi }{10}+\frac{\pi ^2}{80}+\frac{1}{20} \pi 
   \log (2) \\
 6 & -\frac{13}{180}-\frac{13 \pi }{180}+\frac{\pi ^2}{48}+\frac{23 \log (2)}{90} \\
 7 & \frac{73}{315}+\frac{C}{7}-\frac{2 \pi }{21}+\frac{\pi ^2}{112}-\frac{1}{28} \pi
    \log (2) \\
 8 & \frac{29}{420}+\frac{19 \pi }{420}-\frac{22 \log (2)}{105}
\end{array}
\right)$$ Hard to find a pattern.

Comment: How do you know that series that you used?

Comment: What about $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n y^n$?