# Proving $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\log(\sin x))^2dx = \frac{1}{24}\cdot(\pi^3 + 12\pi(\log 2)^2)$

Tags: definite-integrals

Proving

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\log(\sin x))^2dx = \frac{1}{24}\cdot(\pi^3 + 12\pi(\log 2)^2)$$
without making use of gamma function,digamma function, hypergeometric function.

Comment: Do you know complex analysis?

Comment: Alternatively: Do you know Fourier analysis?

Comment: no and no. I prefer to avoid these ways.

Comment: This is proven as $(9)$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/300319).

Comment: @robjohn: this is in my line. Thank you.

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/300061) since it is answered there. The two differ by a factor of $4$.