# Evaluate: $\int_0^{\pi} \ln \left( \sin \theta \right) d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, logarithms

Evaluate: $ \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \ln \left( \sin \theta \right) d\theta$ using [Gauss Mean Value theorem](http://planetmath.org/gaussmeanvaluetheorem).

Given hint: consider $f(z) = \ln ( 1 +z)$.

EDIT:: I know how to evaluate it, but I am looking if I can evaluate it using Gauss MVT.

ADDED:: Here is what I have got so far!!

$$\ln 2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_0^{2\pi } \log(2+e^{i \theta}) d\theta = \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_0^{2\pi } \log(2+e^{-i \theta}) d\theta$$

Hence, $ \displaystyle 2 \ln 2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \log(5 + 4 \cos \theta )d \theta  = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \log(1 + 8 \cos^2 \theta) d \theta$,  now to problem is how to reduce it to the above form?

Comment: But $\ln$ isn't an analytic function on any domain containing the circle around $1$ with radius $1$. Maybe this is a problem.

Comment: Similar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x

Comment: @Cocopuffs i am aware of this question. changing the angle to half angle. I am supposed to use Gauss MVT here.

Comment: Do you know the rule $\log(z) = \log|z| + i \operatorname{Arg} z$?  This and the fact $|1 - e^{i \theta}| = |2 \sin \theta|$ may help. Also, are you from nepal?

Comment: @muzzlator yes that I am.

Comment: @TMM [check revision](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/354795/revisions)!!

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354809/evaluate-int-02-pi-ln1ei-theta-d-theta).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a solution I wrote for a complex analysis assignment several years ago, I hope it helps.  Basically, we are using the mean value theorem you mention above on a slightly different function, and then separating things to obtain the desired integral.  We have to be careful because we can't exactly integrate $\log(1-u)$ on the circle of radius $1$.

> Consider 
>   $$
> \int_{C_{1-\epsilon}}\frac{\log(1-u)}{u}du
> $$
>    where $C_{1-\epsilon}$ is the circle of radius $1-\epsilon$. Then
>   since $\frac{\log(1-u)}{u}$ is an analytic function in $D_{1-\epsilon}$
>   (It has a removable singularity at $u=0$ by the removable singularity
>   theorem mentioned last assignment), we see that this contour integral
>   will be zero for every $\epsilon>0$. But then notice 
>   $$
> \int_{C_{1-\epsilon}}\frac{\log(1-u)}{u}du=2i\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(1-(1-\epsilon)e^{i2z})dz
> $$
>   so that 
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{\pi}\log(1-(1-\epsilon)e^{i2z})dz=0
> $$
>    for every $\epsilon>0$. Since 
>   $$
> |\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(1-e^{i2z})dz|\leq\int_{0}^{\pi}|\log z|dz+\int_{0}^{\pi}|\log(\pi-z)|dz+\int_{0}^{\pi}|\log\left(\frac{1-e^{i2z}}{z(z-\pi)}\right)|dz
> $$
>   As $\frac{1-e^{i2z}}{z(z-\pi)}$ has no zeros on $[0,\pi]$ we see
>   that it must be bounded below by some constant $c$. Then as it also
>   has nontrivial imaginary part on $(0,\pi)$ we see that $\int_{0}^{\pi}|\log\left(\frac{1-e^{i2z}}{z(z-\pi)}\right)|dz<\infty$.
>   Then since $\int_{0}^{1}\log xdx=x\log x-x\biggr|_{x=0}^{x=1}=-1<\infty$
>   it follows that $\int_{0}^{\pi}|\log z|dz<\infty$ and $\int_{0}^{\pi}|\log(\pi-z)|dz<\infty$
>   so that $|\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(1-e^{i2z})dz|<\infty$. Recall $\log$
>   is uniformly continuous on any compact set not containing the origin,
>   so we can bound the middle of all of these integrals by the same constant.
>   Since around $0$ and around $\pi$ the norm of $\log(1-e^{i2z})$
>   goes to infinity, we can choose small enough neighborhoods so that
>   the norm of $\log(1-(1-\epsilon)e^{i2z})dz$ is bounded above by $|\log(1-e^{i2z})|$
>   in these neighborhoods for every $\epsilon>0$. Then applying the
>   dominated convergence theorem tells us that 
>   $$
> \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(1-(1-\epsilon)e^{i2z})dz=\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(1-e^{i2z})dz=0.
> $$
>   Now we have the identity
>   $$
> 1-e^{-2iz}=-2ie^{iz}\sin z
> $$
>   so that
>   $$
> 0=\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(\sin z))dz+\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(e^{iz})dz+\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(-2i)dz.
> $$
>   By choosing the principal branch of the logarithm we then have 
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{\pi}\log(\sin z))dz=-\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}izdz+\int_{0}^{\pi}-\frac{\pi i}{2}dz+\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(2)dz\right)
> $$
>   $$
> =-\left(\frac{i\pi^{2}}{2}+-\frac{\pi^{2}i}{2}dz+\pi\log(2)dz\right)=-\pi\log2.
> $$ By substituting $z=\pi x$ we see that $\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(\sin z))dz=\pi\int_{0}^{1}\log(\sin\pi x))dx$
>   so that we are able to conclude 
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{1}\log(\sin\pi x))dx=-\log2
> $$
>   as desired.

Comment: all right ... thanks!!

Answer (score 33):

I got this as the first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/300319):

> Start with
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
> &=\frac12\int_0^\pi\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\
> &=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(2x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\
> &=\int_0^{\pi/2}\Big(\log(2)+\log(\sin(x))+\log(\cos(x))\Big)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
> &=\frac\pi2\log(2)+2\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   Therefore,
>   $$
> \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac\pi2\log(2)\tag{2}
> $$

Thus,
$$
\int_0^\pi\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=-\pi\log(2)
$$

---

**Using Gauss Mean Value**

$\mathrm{Re}(\log(z))=\log(|z|)=\log\left(\sqrt{2-2\cos(x)}\right)$

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image]
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\pi\log\left(\color{#C00000}{\frac12}\sqrt{2-2\cos(x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\pi\color{#00A000}{\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log\left(\sqrt{2-2\cos(x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}\color{#C00000}{-\pi\log(2)}\\[6pt]
&=\pi\color{#00A000}{\log(1)}-\pi\log(2)\\[12pt]
&=-\pi\log(2)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: (+1.5) the picture itself should worth an extra 1/2 upvote ;-p

Comment: @robjohn I'm not understanding the first line. How does it follow that sin = 1/2 sqrt( 2 - 2 cos)?

Comment: @Mark: We use $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)\implies\sin(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(2x)}2}$. Then, by symmetry and this equation, $$\begin{align}\int_0^\pi\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x &=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(2x)}2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\int_0^\pi\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x)}2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\end{align}$$ The last step is achieved by substituting $x\mapsto x/2$.

Answer (score 11):

This is just for fun.

It is well known that  $\Pi_{1\le k<n}\sin \frac{k\pi}{n}=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$. So $\int_0^\pi \ln \sin x dx =\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\pi}{n}\ln \Pi_{1\le k<n} \sin \frac{k\pi}{n}=-\pi\ln 2 $.

Comment: very interesting!! i knew the identity

Answer (score 4):

$$I=\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \ln \left( \sin \theta \right)\cdot  d\theta$$
$$I=2\times \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left( \sin \theta \right) \cdot d\theta$$
$$I=2\times \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left( \cos \theta \right) \cdot d\theta$$
Adding both.
$$I=\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left( \sin \theta \times \cos \theta\right) \cdot 
d\theta$$
$$I= \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \left(2 \sin \theta\times \cos \theta \right) -\ln2 \cdot d\theta$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin{2\theta})-\ln2 \cdot d\theta$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin{2\theta})\cdot d\theta=I/2$$
So,
$$I=-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln2\cdot d\theta$$
$$I=-{\pi\ln2}$$

Comment: @RonGordon After adding both sides there was $2$ on both side which cancelled. I don't want to write it $again^2$ :).

Comment: My mistake, sorry about that.

Comment: Where is Gauss Mean Value theorem here?

Comment: Aah ! Bounty really get's attention of people. I suddenly got a large attention after a month.

Answer (score 3):

My try:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi}\ln\sin\theta\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left(-\ln 4+\ln4\cos^2\theta\right)d\theta=-\pi\ln 2+\frac12\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\ln(2+2\cos2\theta)d\theta=\\=
-\pi\ln 2+\frac14\underbrace{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left[\ln(1+e^{i\theta})+\ln(1+e^{-i\theta})\right]d\theta}_{=0\;\mathrm{by\; MVT}}=-\pi\ln 2.
\end{align}

Comment: nice explanation................