# Evaluate: $\int_0^{2 \pi} \ln(1+e^{i \theta}) d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^{2 \pi} \ln(1+e^{i \theta}) d\theta$. [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20log%281%2be%5E%28i%20theta%29%29%20from%200%20to%202Pi) is giving $0$. How do I get this result if this is correct?

Attempt:  let $z = e^{i \theta}$, then we have

$$\frac{1}{i}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{\ln (1 +z)}{z} dz $$

[Expading log](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20log%281%2bz%29) at $z=0$ we get analytic function whose contour integration is zero. It this correct?

Comment: What you are doing is right. Note that, you have a pole at $z=0$ in your last integral. Calculating the residue gives you $0$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal ok ok  ... so if i evaluate the contour I would get it zero anyway?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Note that, using the above residue technique, you can evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^{2 \pi}\ln(1+re^{i\theta})d\theta$, By putting $z=re^{i\theta}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Gauss' mean value theorem
$f(z_0)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{i\theta})d\theta$
Using this with $\log (1+z)$ gives us the result.

Comment: I changed my mind (looks like this is okay)... I was confused between $z$ and $\theta$. Still i would like to see more opinion.

Comment: and Gauss MVT is $f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{i\theta})d\theta$

Comment: The use of the Gauss mean value theorem here is wrong, as $\log(1+z)$ is not analytic at $z=-1$.