# Integrate: $\int_0^{\pi} \log ( 1 - 2 r \cos \theta + r^2)d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

If $r \in \Bbb R$ how to integrate $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \log ( 1  - 2 r \cos \theta + r^2)d\theta$?

I need some hints. Special case, if $r = 1$ then I know the above [integral is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/378785/69881).

Here is my working
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi}\log (1 - 2 r \cos \theta + r^2)d\theta &= \int_0^\pi\log ((1 - re^{i \theta})(1 -re^{-i\theta} )) d\theta\\ 
 &= \int_0^\pi \log(1 - r e^{i\theta})d\theta + \int_0^\pi\log(1 - re^{-i\theta})d\theta\\ 
 &= \int_0^{2\pi} \log( 1 - re^{i\theta})d\theta \\
 &= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing $\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(1-2a\cos x+a^2\right) \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650513/computing-int-0-pi-ln-left1-2a-cos-xa2-right-dx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two hints:

1. The integrand is an even function of $\theta$ $\Rightarrow$ the integral can be written as $\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}$.
2. $1-2r\cos\theta+r^2=(1-re^{i\theta})(1-re^{-i\theta})$.

Comment: yeah I got that ... i got $0$, but  if $|r| > 1$ , answer says that $2 \pi \log r$. Don't know if the answer is correct or not.

Comment: then 3rd hint: $1-2r\cos\theta+r^2$ is also equal to $r^2\left(1-r^{-1}e^{i\theta}\right)\left(1-r^{-1}e^{-i\theta}\right)$.

Comment: this works ... but could you explain why two different cases?

Comment: because to expand the function $\ln(1-z)$ into Taylor series around $z=0$, you need $|z|<1$. Then you basically use that for any $n\neq0$ we have $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{in\theta}d\theta=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that when $r<1$ this is the real part of
$$\frac12 \int_{|z|=r} \log(1-z)^2\,\frac{dz}{iz}$$
for the usual branch of $\log$.
When $r>1$, you're going to need to make a branch cut.

Comment: hmmm ... how would i do it? $\log (1-z) = \ln |1 - z| + i \arg ( 1-z)$?? and why do I need to make cut if $r>1$ ?

Comment: No, you should use the Cauchy Integral Formula (or, if you prefer to think of it that way, the Residue Theorem).