# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1}\operatorname d\!x$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Find this integral
$$\operatorname I=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1}\operatorname d\!x$$

My try: let
$$f(x)=x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1$$
I found 
$$f(1-x)=(1-x)^4-2(1-x)^3+2(1-x)^2-x+1=x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1=f(x)$$
so
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\arcsin{\sqrt{(1-x)}}}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1}dx$$
so
$$2I=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}+\arcsin{\sqrt{(1-x)}}}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1}dx$$
then I can't,Thank you very much

Comment: The denominator has four complex roots. May be, performing a decomposition of the denominator in partial fractions would lead to four much simpler integrals. This is just an idea I submit to your sagacity.

Comment: f(1)=1 but your decomposition implies that 1-x divides f(x), so it should be wrong.

Answer (score 18):

This is a very challenging integral which can be solved with brute force. The final answer is

$$\pi\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{78}} \log \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{2 \sqrt{13}-2}}{4} \right)+\pi\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{13}-1}{78}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5+2 \sqrt{13}}}{3} \right)$$

---

***Proof***

Let $I$ denote the integral.

$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin^{-1}\sqrt{x}}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1}dx$$

Substituting $x\mapsto 1-x$ and after averaging both integrals we arrive at

$$I=\frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1}dx$$

Finally substitute $x\mapsto x+\frac{1}{2}$ to get

$$I = \frac{\pi}{4}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{1}{\left( x^2+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{1}{\left( x^2+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx$$

Then we may write
$$
\begin{align*}
I 
&= \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\text{Im}\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{x^2+\frac{1}{4}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}dx \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\text{Im}\left\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}}\right\}_{x=0}^{x=1/2} \\
&= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\text{Im} \left\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-i2\sqrt{3}}}\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-i2\sqrt{3}}}\right\}
\end{align*}
$$

Note that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-i2\sqrt{3}}} = \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{26}}+i\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{26}}$$
So, we can further simplify our previous expression using the following identities

$$
\begin{align*}
\log z &= \log|z|+i\text{arg}z \\
\tan^{-1}z &= \frac{i}{2}\log\left( \frac{1-iz}{1+iz}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
Don't forget to take care over the multivaluedness of logarithms. 
$$
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\text{Im}\left\{\left( \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{26}}+i\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{26}}\right)\tan^{-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{26}}+i\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{26}}\right)\right\} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\text{Im}\Bigg\{ \Bigg( i\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{26}}-\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{26}}\Bigg) \\
&\quad \log\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(3+\sqrt{-5+2 \sqrt{13}}\right)-\frac{i}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(4+\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{15+6 \sqrt{13}}\right)} \right)\Bigg\} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\text{Im}\Bigg\{ \Bigg( i\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{26}}-\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{26}}\Bigg) \\
&\quad \Bigg( \log \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{2 \sqrt{13}-2}}{4} \right)-i \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{5+2 \sqrt{13}}\right)\Bigg)\Bigg\}
\end{align*}
$$ 
Finally separating the imaginary part one gets:

$$\begin{align*}
I &=\pi\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{78}} \log \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{2 \sqrt{13}-2}}{4} \right)+\pi\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{13}-1}{78}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5+2 \sqrt{13}}}{3} \right) \\
&= 0.909520809086566\cdots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Indeed, $$int(arcsin(sqrt(x))/(x^4-2*x^3+2*x^2-x+1), x = 0 .. 1, numeric) $$ produces $0.9095208091 $.

Comment: fyi, Maple 17 gives different answer: `z:=arcsin(sqrt(x))/(x^4-2*x^3+2*x^2-x+1); r:=int(z,x=0..1):
evalf(r);  -.894336814301231-.670856586950946*I`

Comment: @Nasser: Surely you are mistaken. Mathematica's NIntegrate[{ArcSin[Sqrt[x]]/(x^4 - 2 x^3 + 2 x^2 - x + 1)}, {x, 0, 1}] gave 0.9095208.

Comment: I am just showing what Maple gave. Mathematica gives `int = Integrate[ ArcSin[Sqrt[x]]/(x^4 - 2 x^3 + 2 x^2 - x + 1), x];
N[Limit[int, x -> 1] - Limit[int, x -> 0]]` it replied with
`-2.69819 + 1.44222*10^-16 I` may be there is a bug in the symbolic int() but not the numerical version.

Comment: @Nasser: think about what the answer could be.  Do any of the values of the integrand lend themselves to being complex?  Then why would the integral be?  And if Maple is outputting garbage, why attempt to inject doubt in this answer (which is clearly correct and skillfully demonstrated) with such garbage?

Comment: @RonGordon I am simply posting the result from Maple. Do not shoot the messenger if Maple has bugs in it. This is rude of you to do.

Comment: @Nasser: Your original language seemed designed to inject doubt in this answer; that deserves a harsh rebuttal.  If not and you were just pointing out a bug in Maple (which apparently user64494 does not seem to suffer), then there are other forums for that.

Comment: @RonGordon I do not play these games if you do. I was simply saying `FYI` this is what Maple gave. simply an informational message. I did not even follow the solutions shown. I have no idea why you think I want to inject doubt into any one's answer. Why would I do that for? What will I gain? I am simply pointing what another program was finding for this computation. Pure and simple.

Comment: @ Nasser: This is a Maple bug. Every soft has its limitation.

Answer (score 7):

The way you have transformed the integral $I$ is an important step to finding the solution. Using @shobhit.iands's substitution I managed to expand the integrand into two partial fractions whose denominator is a quadratic polynomial. Let $J$ denote

\begin{equation*}
J=2I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arcsin \sqrt{x}+\arcsin \sqrt{1-x}}{x^{4}-2x^{3}+2x^{2}-x+1}dx.\tag{1}
\end{equation*}

For $0\leq x\leq 1$ we have

\begin{equation*}
\arcsin \sqrt{x}+\arcsin \sqrt{1-x}=\frac{\pi }{2}.\tag{2}
\end{equation*}

So

\begin{eqnarray*}
J &=&\frac{\pi }{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{4}-2x^{3}+2x^{2}-x+1}dx, \\
&=&8\pi \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{1}{16u^{4}+8u^{2}+13}\,du,\qquad u=x-\frac{1}{
2} \\
&=&16\pi \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{1}{16u^{4}+8u^{2}+13}\,du.\tag{3}
\end{eqnarray*}

The polynomial in the denominator can be factored as follows

\begin{eqnarray*}
16u^{4}+8u^{2}+13 &=&16\left[ \left( u-u_{1}\right) (u-u_{2})\right] \left[
\left( u-u_{3}\right) (u-u_{4})\right]  \\
&=&\left[ 4\left( u-u_{1}\right) (u-u_{2})\right] \left[ 4\left(
u-u_{3}\right) (u-u_{4})\right] ,
\end{eqnarray*}

where $u_{k},k=1,2,3,4$, are its roots

\begin{eqnarray*}
u_{1} &=&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-1+i\sqrt{12}},u_{3}=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-1+i\sqrt{12}} \\
u_{2} &=&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-1-i\sqrt{12}},u_{4}=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-1-i\sqrt{12}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Since

\begin{eqnarray*}
4\left( u-u_{1}\right) (u-u_{2}) &=&4u^{2}-2\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}u+\sqrt{13}
\\
4\left( u-u_{3}\right) (u-u_{4}) &=&4u^{2}+2\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}u+\sqrt{13},
\end{eqnarray*}

we obtain

\begin{equation*}
16u^{4}+8u^{2}+13=(4u^{2}-2\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}u+\sqrt{13})(4u^{2}+2\sqrt{
-2+2\sqrt{13}}u+\sqrt{13})
\end{equation*}

and are thus able to expand the integrand into partial fractions

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{16u^{4}+8u^{2}+13} &=&\frac{1}{(4u^{2}-2\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}u+\sqrt{
13})(4u^{2}+2\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}u+\sqrt{13})} \\
&=&-\frac{1}{312}\frac{\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}(\sqrt{13}+13)u-12\sqrt{13}}{
4u^{2}-2\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}u+\sqrt{13}} \\
&&+\frac{1}{312}\frac{\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}(\sqrt{13}+13)u+12\sqrt{13}}{
4u^{2}+2\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}u+\sqrt{13}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence

\begin{eqnarray*}
J &=&-\frac{2\pi }{39}\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}(\sqrt{13}
+13)u-12\sqrt{13}}{4u^{2}-2\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}u+\sqrt{13}}\,du \\
&&+\frac{2\pi }{39}\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}(\sqrt{13}+13)u+12
\sqrt{13}}{4u^{2}+2\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}u+\sqrt{13}}\,du.\tag{4}
\end{eqnarray*}

In this way we have reduced the evaluation of $J$ to the evaluation (see [this entry](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions#Integrands_of_the_form_xm_.2F_.28a_x2_.2B_b_x_.2B_c.29n) of Wikipedia ) of two integrals of rational functions of the form

\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{mu+n}{au^{2}+bu+c}du=\left. \frac{m}{2a}\ln \left\vert
au^{2}+bu+c\right\vert +\frac{2an-bm}{a\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}\arctan \frac{2au+b}{
\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}\right\vert _{0}^{1/2},
\end{equation*}

where

\begin{equation*}
4ac-b^{2}=4\times 4\times \sqrt{13}-(2\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}})^{2}=8\sqrt{13}
+8>0.
\end{equation*}

ADDED. I've got

\begin{eqnarray*}
I =\frac{J}{2}&=&\frac{\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}\left( \sqrt{13}+13\right) \pi }{
312}\ln \frac{1+\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}+\sqrt{13}}{1-\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}}+\sqrt{
13}} \\
&&-\frac{2\left( -2+2\sqrt{13}\right) \left( \sqrt{13}+13\right) \pi }{312
\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{13}}}\arctan \frac{12}{\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{13}}\left( -7+\sqrt{13}
\right) }\tag{5} \\
&\approx &0.90952.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, as shown in @Ron Gordon's answer, we should eliminate the $\arcsin(\sqrt{x})$ in the numerator. Take the substitution that $\arcsin(\sqrt{x})=t$, then
\begin{equation}
I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{t\sin(2t)}{\sin(t)^8-2\sin(t)^6+2\sin(t)^4-\sin(t)^2+1}dt\\
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{t\sin(2t)}{115/128+1/128\cos(8t)+3/32\cos(4t)}dt\\
\end{equation}
By taking $t'=\pi/2-t$, we can check
\begin{equation}
I=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(2t)}{115/128+1/128\cos(8t)+3/32\cos(4t)}dt\\
=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1}dx\\
=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x^2-x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx\\
=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\frac{1}{((x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4})^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx\\
\stackrel{y=x-1/2}{=}\frac{\pi}{4}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{1}{(y^2+\frac{1}{4})^2+\frac{3}{4}}dy
\end{equation}
Also, I do not have some good manner to solve it but to factorize the denominator in complex. We can easy to get the 4 roots of the denominator that
\begin{equation}
x_{1,2}=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-1-2i\sqrt{3}}\\
x_{3,4}=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-1+2i\sqrt{3}}
\end{equation}
Then, you can factorize the last fraction by solve the following problem:
\begin{equation}
\frac{C_1x+C_2}{x-x_1}+\frac{C_3x+C_4}{x-x_2}+\frac{C_5x+C_6}{x-x_3}+\frac{C_7x+C_8}{x-x_4}=\frac{1}{(y^2+\frac{1}{4})^2+\frac{3}{4}}
\end{equation}
By doing this, you can get the solution of $I$. Since the result is too long I ignore them. The approximation of the result is $0.9095208091$. I think there must be some easier method to deal with the integral of rational fraction.

Comment: You beat me to the punch.  The Weierstrass stuff I posted is ill-advised.

Comment: @RonGordon You are modesty. I think my method to deal with the integral of rational fraction is but a general way. There seem like be a more easier method to calculate that such as using residue theorem. But I have no idea how to achieve that now.

Comment: Why down my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin \sqrt{x}}{x^4-2 x^3+2 x^2-x+1} d x$$
Then $x\mapsto 1-x$ transforms the integral into
$$
I=\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin \sqrt{1-x}}{x^4-2 x^3+2 x^2-x+1} d x
$$
Averaging these two versions of $I$ yields

$$
I=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin \sqrt{x}+\arcsin \sqrt{1-x}}{x^4-2 x^3+2 x^2-x+1} d x
$$

Noting that
$$\arcsin \sqrt{x}+\arcsin \sqrt{1-x} =\frac{\pi}{2},  $$
we have

$$
I=\frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^4-2 x^3+2 x^2-x+1} d x 
$$

Letting $u=x-\frac{1}{2}  $ simplifies the denominator of the integrand as

\begin{aligned}
I & =4\pi \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{16 u^4+8 u^2+13} d u \\
& = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{u^4+\frac{1}{2} u^2+\frac{13}{16}} d u \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2}  \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\frac{1}{u^2}}{u^2+\frac{13}{16 u^2}+\frac{1}{2}} d u \\
& =\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{13}} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4 u^2}\right)-\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4 u^2}\right)}{u^2+\frac{13}{16 u^2}+\frac{1}{2}} d u \\&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{13}}\left[\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{d\left(u-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}\right)}{\left(u-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}\right)^2+\frac{\sqrt{13}+1}{2}}-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{d\left(u+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}\right)}{\left(u+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}\right)^2-\frac{\sqrt{13}-1}{2}}\right]\\&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{13}}\left[\sqrt{\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}+1}}\left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{13}+1}{2}}}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}-1}} \ln \left|\frac{u+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{13}-1}{2}}}{u+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}}}\right|\right)\right]_0^{\frac 12}  \\ & =\pi \sqrt{\frac{2}{13+\sqrt{13}}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{26}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}+1}}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{26}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}+1}}\right)\right] +\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{13-\sqrt{13}}} \ln \left| \frac{2 \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{26}+4 \sqrt{\sqrt{13}-1}}{2 \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{26}-4 \sqrt{\sqrt{13}-1}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{26}-4 \sqrt{\sqrt{13}-1}}{\sqrt{26}+4 \sqrt{\sqrt{13}-1}}\right|
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

Here are some residue-theorem-friendly forms, though how friendly is debatable.

---

Rewrite $\arcsin x\to\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x$, then substitute $y=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-x}x}$:

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan \sqrt{\frac{1-x}x}}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1} \, dx \\
&= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan y}{\frac1{(1+y^2)^4}-\frac2{(1+y^2)^3}+\frac2{(1+y^2)^2}-\frac1{1+y^2}+1} \, \frac{y}{(1+y^2)^2} \, dy \\
&= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{y (1+y^2)^2 \arctan y}{1+3y^2+5y^4+3y^6+y^8} \, dy \tag{$\star$}
\end{align*}$$

Now we can theoretically approach $(\star)$ as a more intricate flavor of [integral $J(a,b,c)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4821505/170231) and integrate a similar $f(z)$ along the same contour.

---

On the other hand, substituting $y\to\dfrac1y$ to exploit $\arctan y+\arctan\dfrac1y=\dfrac\pi2$, then $y\to\sqrt y$, reduces $(\star)$ to

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \frac\pi2 \int_0^\infty \frac{y (y^2+1)^2}{y^8+3y^6+5y^4+3y^2+1} \, dy \\
&= \frac\pi4 \int_0^\infty \frac{(y+1)^2}{y^4+3y^3+5y^2+3y+1} \, dy
\end{align*}$$

which can be computed with the typical [keyhole contour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#/media/File:Keyhole_contour.svg), considering the integral of

$$f(z) = \frac{(z+1)^2}{z^4+3z^3+5z^2+3z+1} \log z$$