# Monstrous integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

**How to show the following**

> $$\displaystyle
>  \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1}dx  \\ =
>  \pi\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{78}} \log \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{2
>  \sqrt{13}-2}}{4} \right)+\pi\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{13}-1}{78}}\tan
>  ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5+2 \sqrt{13}}}{3} \right)$$

It seems that it can be transformed into an elliptic integral. Maybe we can define

$$I(a) = \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\arcsin{a\sqrt{x}}}{x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1}dx $$

Then by differentiation

$$I'(a) = \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{(\sqrt{1-a^2x})(x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x+1)}dx $$

Another approach might involve series expansion of $\arcsin(x)$

$$\arcsin(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{{2n \choose n} }{4^n(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}$$

To be honest it seems helpless.

**Reference**

http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic808.html

Comment: Related: [Identical integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683454/evaluating-int-01-frac-arcsin-sqrtxx4-2x32x2-x1-operatorname) — [Search result from Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Carcsin%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D%7D%7D%7Bx%5E4-2x%5E3%2B2x%5E2-x%2B1%7Ddx%24&p=1).

Comment: @FrenzyLi, thanks.