# $L^2$ norm of Green function for the Laplace equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, estimation, greens-function

I am referring to the following post:
[Estimate the Green function for the Laplace equation in 2D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461191/estimate-the-green-function-for-the-laplace-equation-in-2d),
where there has been found an explicit expression for the integral
$$\int\limits_{|y| \leq 1} G(x,y) \, dy$$
where $G$ is the Green function for the Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation in the two dimensional unit disk.

Now I am trying to find out whether the following integral exists and if it does, how one could find an upper bound:

$$\int\limits_{|y| \leq 1} (G(x,y))^2 \, dy$$

Or even better, I am interested in the $L^2$ norm of $G$ over the unit disk (if it exists).

The culculaiton above will probably not work as we have to deal with a more complicated integral. So does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Sorry to ask another question, instead of answering, but how can you be sure that the integral is finite?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I am not sure. I should better ask whether it can be shown that it is finite and if yes, how it can be bounded. I will add this. Thanks!

Comment: Do I misunderstand things, or isn't $G(x,y)$ a constant multiple of $\log|x-y|$?

Comment: @paulgarrett Kind of...It is $G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln \frac{|x-y|}{|x| \bigl|y - \frac{x}{|x|^2}\bigr|}$. Is the existence/non-existence obvious?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not read your question carefully... was thinking of the free-space Green's function... But, still, this is such a symmetrical situation that something should be clear. (Give me some hours... I'll come back to this if no one else has anything to say...)

Comment: I am too lazy/busy at the moment to carry this out, but I would treat the disc as being in $\mathbb C$, and use the fact that Moebius/linear-fractional transformations are transitive on the disk, and are holomorphic. Thus, with $\log |z|$ holomorphic except at $0$, use a Moebius transform to move $0$ to any other $w$ in the disk...

Comment: I have this vague idea of using the [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Complex_homography) as a change of variable, so that we are reduced to $\iint_{y>0} G(x, y)^2 J(x,y)\, dxdy, $ where $G$ is now the Green function of the upper half-plane and $w$ is the Jacobian of the Cayley transform. This should be slightly easier but I am totally out of focus in these days and I cannot perform the computation right now.