# Find the integral of log(1 - a/x^2 + 1/x^4) from 0 to infinity

Tags: calculus, integration

It is a exercise from Calculus appeared in improper integral, one of my classmates ask me. It reads as follows:
$\int_{0}^{\infty} \log(1-\frac{a}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}) dx = ?$, where a is a parameter and a<2.

I have tried to let t = $\frac{1}{x}$ and rewrite LHS as $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1-\frac{a}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4})}{x^2} dx$. Or write it as $\int_{0}^{\infty} \log(x^4 - ax^2 +1) dx$ $-\int_{0}^{\infty} 4\log(x) dx$ in a more simple form. But I still cannot calculate it directly. I wonder whether we should use more delicate techniques to solve the problem?
I know it does not contain any philosophy in this problem but I would like to regard it as an intelligent challenge.
I would appreciate it if anyone can give me some insights.

Comment: What is $a$. For large values of $a$ the integrand is not well defined.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty log(x)dx$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3144140/186817

(replace $a$ by $-\frac{a}{2}$ into the formula)

The desired result is $\pi\sqrt{2-a}$

(Observe that one needs $a\leq 2$ )

Answer (score 2):

If $|a|\le 2$, the parameterisation $a=2\cos 2\theta$ obtains [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143523/proving-int-0-infty-log-left-1-2-frac-cos-2-thetax2-frac1x4-rig/) as $2\pi\sin\theta$, i.e. $\pi\sqrt{2-a}$. If $a>2$, there are real values of $a$ for which the logarithm's argument is negative, so that the integrand is non-real. The former case can presumably be analytically continued to $a<-2$.