# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1+\frac{2\cos x}{x^2} +\frac{1}{x^4}) \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Numerical evidence suggests the following

> $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln\left(1+\frac{2\cos x}{x^2} +\frac{1}{x^4}\right) \, dx\stackrel{?}{=}4\pi W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=4.42\cdots$$
> where $W(x)$ is the Lambert $W$ (product log) function.

Here’s the context for the problem:

I was playing around with other $\ln$ integrals, and evaluated the following:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln \left(1+2x^{-2} \cos(\phi)+x^{-4}\right)\,dx=2\pi\cos \left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)$$ There are several questions on MSE on similar integrals to the above, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143523).
The above integral can be evaluated in several ways, but I just chose to introduce a $\ln(z)$ integral representation. I was curious to know what the integral would instead be if I replaced $\cos \phi$ with $\cos x$. $I$ converges because it is bounded above by the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln (1+2x^{-2}+x^{-4})\,dx=2\pi$.

Here are my attempts:

Although I’m much more comfortable with real analysis, I currently have no method that I can apply real analytic techniques or representations on $I$. I tried instead contour integration:

Firstly notice that $$I \stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2+2x^2 \cos x+x^3 \sin x}{1+x^4 +2x^2 \cos x} \, dx$$

I then converted these trig functions into exponential forms and factorised the denominator to determine where the poles are- they are the four solutions to $x^2+e^{i x} = 0$ and $x^2+e^{-i x}=0$ which are
$$x=\pm 2i W\left(\pm \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

I then took a semi-circular arc in the upper half plane to be my contour as the integrand is even, and computed the following residues:

$$\text{Res} \left[f(z),\,2i W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] =-2i W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$\text{Res} \left[f(z),\,-2i W\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] =2i W\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
where $f(x)$ is the integrand function above.

So we have then that
$$\oint_C f(z) \, dz=2I + \int_{\Gamma} f(z) \, dz = -4\pi \left(W\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) -W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$
where $\int_{\Gamma}$ traces the semi-circular arc path. Here is where I’m stuck however because I’m not sure how to evaluate this arc integral.

Comment: The Lambert W function has infinitely many branches, which means that  $x^{2}+e^{ix}=0$ and $x^{2}+e^{-ix}=0$ have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: However, in [some cases](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/207639), some of the infinitely many roots cancel.

Comment: Ah, I had completely forgotten about the infinite branches of Lambert $W$. From looking at the complex plot of the integrand, it has infinitely many poles… I’m not sure how to approach this integral at all at the moment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For $a>0$, let $F(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(1+\frac{e^{aix}}{x^2})\, dx$, your $I$ equals $\Re F(1)$. By parts gives
$$F(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2-i a x}{1+x^2 e^{-i a x}} \,dx$$
When $a=1$, I claim $f_a(z) = 1+z^2 e^{-a iz}$ has a unique root $z=2i W(1/2)$ on the upper half plane $\mathcal{H}$, then residue theorem (one also shows integral on big semicircle tends to $0$, this is not difficult) yields your claim.

---

For the claim: let $z_0$ be a root of $f_a$ in $\mathcal{H}$, then $|z_0|^2 = e^{-a \Im(z_0)} < 1$. Therefore all roots of $f_a$ in $\mathcal{H}$ lie in semicircle of radius $1$.

The number of roots can be found by evaluating (numerically) the contour integral (always an integer): $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma f_a'(z)/f_a(z) dz$. The Mathematica command

```
f[x_] := x^2*Exp[-I*x] + 1; 1/(2 Pi*I)*NIntegrate[f'[z]/f[z], {z, -1, 1, 1 + I, -1 + I, -1}]
```

evaluates above integral over rectangle with indicated vertices, it outputs $1$, so there is only one root of $f_1$ in $\mathcal{H}$. One checks $z=2iW(1/2)$ is a root, so the only root.

For general $a>0$, $f_a$ might have many roots in $\mathcal{H}$, $F(a)$ is a finite sum of Lambert W over different branches.

Comment: Great solution. Is there a way to analyse this without Mathematica?

Comment: @FShrike If you don't want to numerically evaluate the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma f_a'(z)/f_a(z) dz$, you almost always need to do some estimation, and they're not always enlightening. You can get a feeling of such estimation by browsing questions under the hat "Rouché's theorem" on this site.

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Comment: If you replace  the **NIntegrate** by **Integrate**, I suppose that you should receive as an answer $$-\frac{i \left(i+2 i \pi +\log \left(1+e^{-i}\right)-\log
   \left(1+e^i\right)\right)}{2 \pi }$$ which is $1$ (for sure). $$\frac{1+2 \pi -i \log \left(1+e^{-i}\right)+i \log \left(1+e^i\right)}{2 \pi }$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Of course this is expected because $\int  f'/f  = \log f$. But this is an unwise way to look at the matter, because $\log f$ has branches.

Answer (score 2):

*This not an answer at all*

Doing almost the same thing as you did with $\cos(\phi)$, I considered
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \log\Bigg[1+\frac{2a}{x^2} +\frac{1}{x^4}\Bigg] \, dx=\frac{a+1+\sqrt{a^2-1}}{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}}\pi$$

For $-1\leq a \leq 1$, the function $I(a)$ looks very much like $\left[1+W(\text{something})\right]$.

On the other hand, you noticed that $\left(4 W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\sqrt{2}\right)$ is very small $(-0.00728)$.

Making $a=\cosh(t)$ gives amazing results.

**Edit**

Just by curiosity, plot on the same graph for $-1\leq a \leq 1$
$$f(a)=\frac{a+1+\sqrt{a^2-1}}{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}}\pi\quad \text{and}\quad g(a)=\sqrt{2} \pi  \left(1+W\left(\frac{a}{e}\right)\right)$$
Computing the norm
$$\int_{-1}^{+1} \Big[f(a)-g(a)\big]^2\,da=0.185562$$