# Integrate $\int_{3-2\sqrt{2}}^{3+2\sqrt{2}} \frac{\ln x}{x\sqrt{-x^2+6x-1}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, real-numbers

How to integrate $$\int_{3-2\sqrt{2}}^{3+2\sqrt{2}} \frac{\ln x}{x\sqrt{-x^2+6x-1}}\, dx$$

I believe the exact value of this integral cannot be found , however there could be a way I am not aware of. If not, is it possible to put into a familiar form using other functions such as $Li(x)$ for example.

After some attempts i am still lost and Mathematica is not too helpful.

Thank you kindly for your help and time.

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: maybe do $dv=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}dx$ $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2+6x-1}}$

Comment: Did you try trapz or simpsons rule?

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\ln$ using `\ln`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky Im afraid none of those have helped so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substitute $x=\frac1{3-2\sqrt2\cos t}$ to get

\begin{align}
& \int_{3-2\sqrt{2}}^{3+2\sqrt{2}} \frac{\ln x}{x\sqrt{-x^2+6x-1}}\, dx\\
= & \int_0^\pi \ln(3-2\sqrt2 \cos t) dt\\
=& \int_0^\pi [\ln2+\ln(1+  \frac12-\frac2{\sqrt2 }\cos t) ]dt=\pi\ln2
\end{align}
where $\int_0^\pi \ln(1+ a^2-2a\cos t)dt=0$ with $a=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ is used.
[Computing $\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(1-2a\cos x+a^2\right) \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650513/computing-int-0-pi-ln-left1-2a-cos-xa2-right-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Letting $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}  $ transforms the integral
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{-x^2+6 x-1}} d x \\
& =-\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{8-(x-3)^2}} d x,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\alpha, \beta = 3\mp 2\sqrt 2$ and $\alpha \beta =1.$

Putting $x-3=\sqrt{8} \cos \theta$ changes
$$
I= \int_0^\pi \ln (3+\sqrt{8} \cos \theta) d \theta
$$
By my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4470820/732917), we have
$$
\boxed{I =\pi \ln \left(\frac{3+\sqrt{3^2-(\sqrt{8})^2}}{2}\right) =\pi \ln 2}
$$

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

Put $$x=\frac 1t$$

and observe that
$$\frac{1}{3-2\sqrt{2}}=3+2\sqrt{2}$$

The integral becomes
$$\int_{3-\sqrt{8}}^{3+\sqrt{8}}\frac{\ln(t)}{\sqrt{8-(t-3)^2}}dt$$
Now, we put
$$(t-3)=\sqrt{8}\sin(u)$$
with
$$dt=\sqrt{8}\cos(u)du$$

this yields to

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(3+\sqrt{8}\sin(u))du$$

Comment: Are you sure this will help?

Comment: Could you post a full answer?