# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x)dx$$
Basically, I have tried all the definite integrals formula I know, but nothing works. Please help me. I can't figure out actually how to handle this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may just set $x=\arctan t$ then perform an integration by parts to reduce the problem to the integration of a rational function.

Comment: Differentiate with respect to either $a$ or $b$ and use the tangent half angle substitution.  Then integrate the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the known result [$\int^{\pi}_{0}
{\ln(1+r^2 -2r\cos t)}dt=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650513/computing-int-0-pi-ln-left1-2a-cos-xa2-right-dx) to obtain

\begin{align}
& \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}{\ln{\left(a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x\right)}dx}\\
= & \frac12\int^{\pi}_{0}{\ln{\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}2-\frac{a^2-b^2}2\cos t\right)}dt}\\
 = & \frac12\int^{\pi}_{0}
{\ln\left( \left(\frac{|a|+|b|}2\right)^2\cdot (1+r^2 -2r\cos t)\right)}dt
,\>\>\> r=\frac{|a|-|b|}{|a|+|b|}\\
 = & \pi\ln\frac{|a|+|b|}2
\end{align}