# Determine if the following integral is convergent or divergent. If it is convergent find its value.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The next week I have a test over Improper Integrals and yesterday started to solve some problems that I've found on th Internet. Everything was fine until I stuck on this example:

> Determine if the following integral is convergent or divergent.  If it is convergent find its value - $$\int^{\pi/2}_{0} \ln(\cos x)dx$$

Any ideas how to test the integral is convergent or divergent?

Comment: Compare it to $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\sin x\,dx$, and compare that one to $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log x\,dx$.

Comment: For evaluation see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354795/evaluate-int-0-pi-ln-left-sin-theta-right-d-theta)

Comment: @Gerry Myerson - sorry but I  didn't get it. Could explain a bit more?

Comment: You thought about my suggestions for all of 4 minutes. Please, think about them seriously.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand why I have to compare it with logsinx

Comment: @NoSense You don't _have_ to compare it to that. Rather, you could transform it to that ($\theta = \pi/2 - x$), and then comparing $\sin \theta$ to $\theta$ shows the convergence.

Comment: Ha, it was so simple...thanks Daniel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that, on $[0,\pi/2]$

$$\tag 1 0\geq \log\cos x\geq \log\left(1-\frac 2\pi x\right)$$

and the latter is an integrable lower bound. The function $$\varphi(\varepsilon)=\int_0^{\pi/2-\varepsilon}\log\cos x dx$$ decreases monotonically as $\varepsilon \to\frac \pi 2^-$, and is bounded below by $(1)$, so it converges.

Comment: How do I know that logcosx > log(1-2/pi*x)?

Comment: @NoSense It suffices that you check that $\cos x\geq 1-\frac 2\pi x$. Can you do that?

Comment: aha, I will try to do it myself, thanks for the help