# How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} $ $(2+\cos \frac{i \pi}{n})^{\frac{\pi}{n}}$=$\sqrt{3}$ by the sum form of a integration?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The integral seems like

$$
\exp\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\left[\ln(2+\cos\left(x\right)\right)]\,{\rm d}x\right)
$$

but the above will be a number bigger than $5$ by appraisement.

[image: This is the original problem.]

Comment: Don't forget that when you go from product to sum you have to move the logarithm inside to the individual terms!  Your 'final form' is missing that logarithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking log, 
\begin{align*}
\log \left( \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}   \left( 2 + \cos \left( \frac{i \pi}{ n } \right ) \right )^{\frac \pi n}\right ) &= 
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac \pi n  \log \left(  2 + \cos \left( \frac{ i \pi}{n}\right ) \right ) \\ 
 &= \pi  \cdot \frac {1}{n } \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  \log \left(  2 + \cos \left( \frac{ i \pi}{n}\right ) \right )\\
\end{align*}

Taking limit 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty } \frac \pi  n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  \log \left(  2 + \cos \left( \frac{ i \pi}{n}\right ) \right )  =  \int_0^\pi \log(2 + \cos(x))dx  = \pi  \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)\right) $$
Taking back to $e$, we get 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \prod_{k=0}^\infty \left( 2 + \cos \left( \frac{i \pi }{n } \right ) \right )^{\frac \pi n } = e^{\pi  \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)\right) } = \left( \frac 1 2 (  2 + \sqrt 3) \right )^\pi $$

Putting

> `N[Product[(2 + Cos[k Pi/10^3])^(Pi/10^3), {k, 0, 10^3}]]`

on Mathematica produces the value of $7.10988$ which is close to our [calculated value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282%2bsqrt%283%29%29/2%29%5EPi) so I think what you claim on title must be false.

**To evaluate the integral**, we proceed in the following way.
$$\int_0^{\pi}  \log \left( 2 + \cos(\theta) \right )d\theta  = \frac 1 2 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \log \left( 2 + \cos(\theta) \right )d\theta  = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} \log(2 + \cos(\theta))d\theta $$

From [Gauss MVT](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354795/evaluate-int-0-pi-ln-left-sin-theta-right-d-theta) we get, 
$$\int_0^{2\pi } \left(\log ( \sqrt 3 + 2 + e^{i\theta})+\log ( \sqrt 3 +  2 + e^{-i\theta}) \right ) d\theta  = 4 \pi  \log (\sqrt 3 + 2 )$$

\begin{align*}
 4 \pi  \log (\sqrt 3 + 2 ) &=\int_0^{2\pi } \left(\log (\sqrt 3  + 2 + e^{i\theta})+\log (\sqrt 3 +  2 + e^{-i\theta}) \right ) d\theta \\ 
 &= \int_0^{2\pi} \log \left( ( \sqrt 3+2 )^2 + 1 + ( \sqrt 3 +2)2 \cos \theta  \right )d\theta\\ 
 &= \int_0^{2\pi } \log \left( 4(2 + \sqrt 3) + 2 (2 + \sqrt 3) \cos (\theta) \right )  d\theta \\ 
 &=  \int_0^{2\pi }\log(2(2 + \sqrt 3))d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi } \log(2 + \cos\theta)d\theta\\  
 &= 2 \pi \log (2 (2 + \sqrt 3 )) + \int_0^{2\pi } \log(2 + \cos\theta)d\theta \\  
\end{align*}

Which gives 
$$2\pi \log \left( \frac{(2 + \sqrt 3 )^2}{2 (2 + \sqrt 3 )}\right )= \int_0^{2\pi } \log(2 + \cos\theta)d\theta $$
Taking half of it give the value of our integral as evaluated by Mathematica earlier.

> $$\pi \log \left( \frac{2 + \sqrt 3 }{2 }\right )= \int_0^{\pi } \log(2 + \cos\theta)d\theta $$

Comment: A '2' magically became a '1' in your penultimate equality...

Comment: @experimentX How do you copmute the integration?

Comment: @frame99 currently I am using Mathematica to evaluate the intgral, and thinking ... I think i'll have to resort to complex analysis to evaluate this integral. I'll update if it find it.

Comment: @experimentX The $pi$ is redundant.