# Show that if $|a|\le 1$, then $\int^{2\pi}_0 {\log|1-ae^{i\theta}|}\, d\theta =0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that if $|a|\le1$, then $\int^{2\pi}_0 {\log|1-ae^{i\theta}|} \,d\theta =0$

This is from Stein's [*Complex Analysis*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691113858).

I think that if $|a|<1$ then the function $\log|1-ae^{i\theta}|$ is holomorphic in the unit disk so the integral is clearly zero.

> Am I making a mistake? What is the solution when $|a|=1$?

Help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: when $a=1$, $\lim_{\theta\to \pi}\ln|1-ae^{i\theta}|=-\infty$

Comment: $\log|1-az|$ is real valued on the unit disc, so certainly not holomorphic. Also, that is beside the point: you are integrating over a *real* interval. Try transforming the integral to a complex curve integral first.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Cauchy formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), you can show [that](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssMean-ValueTheorem.html) 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \log (1 - ae^{i\theta}) d\theta = 2\pi\log (1) = 0 \tag{1}$$

Similarly (going counter clockwise direction) you can show that 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \log (1 - ae^{-i\theta}) d\theta = 2\pi\log (1) = 0 \tag{2}$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ you get the required result.
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \log |1 - ae^{i\theta}|^2 d\theta = 0 $$

**ADDED::** looks like I need strict inequality for above :S for case $a=1$, the integral you need to evaluate is 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \log \sqrt{(1-\cos x)^2 + \sin^2x}dx = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac 1 2 \log (2- 2\cos(x) )dx  \\ 
= \pi \log 2 + \frac 1 2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \log (1 - \cos(x))dx \tag{3}$$

Then integral converges because we know $\int_0^1 \log(x) dx $ converges and there is only two finite points where $\log(x)$ tends to singularity.

The integral on the right is $-\pi \log(2)$ making the whole expression zero.

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \log(1 - \cos(x)) dx = \int_0^{2\pi} \log(2 \sin^2 (x/2) )dx = 2 \pi \log (2) + 4 \int_0^{\pi} \log(\sin(y)) dy \tag{4}$$

The last integral is pretty famous, you can find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354795/evaluate-int-0-pi-ln-left-sin-theta-right-d-theta) and use it's value and show that the whole expression on $(3)$ is zero.

Comment: :in the case $|a|=1$,can we assume $a=1$ WLOG?

Comment: @user115608 yes you can ... since $a = 1 e^{i\phi}$ and constant argument is not going to make any difference since we are going around the circles