# Solving the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}{\log(\sin x)}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> Solve this integral$$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\log(\sin x)}\,\mathrm dx$$

I have tried this by breaking the limit from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ to $\pi$, but I am unable to solve the 2nd part.

Comment: Also, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x).

Comment: Then, there is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/354795).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the integral as you mentioned works:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\ln (\sin(x))dx &= \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))dx+\int\limits_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\ln(\sin(x))dx\\
&= \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))dx+\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos(x))dx\\
&=
\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)\right)dx\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\sin(2x)\right)dx-
\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(2)dx\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\ln(\sin(x))dx-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$

and therefore:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\ln (\sin(x))dx =-\pi\ln 2$$

Comment: I think that will be -π/2 ln 2 in the before last line

Comment: @AtanuSaha, yes, my bad. You are right.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/378785).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry):

$$\begin{align}\int\ln(\sin(x))\,\mathrm dx&\equiv\int\ln\left(\dfrac{\mathrm i}2\left(\exp(-\mathrm ix) - \exp(\mathrm ix)\right)\right)\,\mathrm dx \\ &= \int\ln(\exp(-\mathrm ix) - \exp(\mathrm ix)) + \ln\left(\dfrac{\mathrm i}2\right)\,\mathrm du\end{align}$$

Let $u = \mathrm ix\implies\mathrm du = \mathrm i\mathrm dx$. Therefore,

$$\begin{align}\int\ln(\exp(-\mathrm ix) - \exp(\mathrm ix)) + \ln\left(\dfrac{\mathrm i}2\right)\,\mathrm du&\equiv-\mathrm i\int\ln(\exp(-u) + \exp(u)) + \ln\left(\dfrac{\mathrm i}2\right)\,\mathrm du \\ &=-\mathrm i\int\ln\left(\exp(-u) + \exp(u)\right)\,\mathrm du -\mathrm i\int\ln\left(\dfrac{\mathrm i}2\right)\,\mathrm du\end{align}$$

Solve the integral $$\int\ln\left(\exp(-u) + \exp(u)\right)\,\mathrm du$$ by parts by setting $$\begin{align}f = \ln(\exp(-u) + \exp(u))&\implies f' = \dfrac{-\exp(-u) - \exp(u)}{\exp(-u) - \exp(u)}, \\ g' = 1 &\implies g = u.\end{align}$$

Comment: How does this help can you explain further?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
use integration by parts:
$$x\ln\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)\Big|_0^\pi-\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cot\left(x\right)$$