# How to solve $\int\limits_0^1 \ln(x!) dx$?

Tags: integration, logarithms, factorial

So in the given question, we have to evaluate the given integral which is $\int\limits_0^1 \ln(x!) dx$

My initial thought is to simplify factorial x inside logarithmic function.

$\implies\int\limits_0^1 \ln((x) \cdot(x-1)\cdot(x-2) \cdot\cdot\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1) dx$

$\implies\int\limits_0^1 \ln(x) + \ln(x-1) +\ln(x-2) +...+\ln(2) + \ln(1)dx$

$\implies\int\limits_0^1 \ln(x) dx+ \int\limits_0^1\ln(x-1) dx+\int\limits_0^1\ln(x-2) dx+...+\int\limits_0^1\ln(2)dx + \int\limits_0^1\ln(1)dx$

Does this make any sense?

---

The another method which I thought:

$\int\limits_0^1 \ln(x!) dx = \int\limits_0^1 \ln(\Gamma(x+1)) dx$

or

$\int\limits_0^1 \ln(x!) dx = \int\limits_0^1 \ln(\int\limits_0^\infty t^x\cdot e^{-t} dt) dx$

- Can I proceed in any of the two methods which I used?
- Is there any easier/different method to solve it?

Comment: See [polygamma function $ψ^{(a)}(b)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/) with $a=-1$.

Comment: For $x\in[0,1]$ the expansion $x!=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots2\cdot1$ makes no sense; nor does $\ln(x-1)$, etc., since the natural logarithm is not (naturally) defined on the negative reals, which $x-1$ etc. will be.

Comment: No mathematician nowadays writes $x!$ for non-integer $x$.  Maybe in the 19th century they did.  Now you should write it in terms of the $\Gamma$ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 0.**
$$\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$$

**Hint 1.**
$$I = \int_0^1 \ln\Gamma(x+1)dx = \underbrace{\int_0^1\ln(x)dx}_{I_1} + \underbrace{\int_0^1\ln\Gamma(x) dx}_{I_2}$$

**Hint 2.**
$$I_2 = \int_0^1\ln\Gamma(x) dx = \int_0^1\ln\Gamma(1- x) dx \\
2I_2 = I_2+I_2 = \int_0^1\ln\Gamma(x) dx + \int_0^1\ln\Gamma(1- x) dx = \int_0^1\ln\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x) dx$$

**Hint 3.**
$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$$

**Hint 4.** Putting all together, you will have to know how to solve a classical integral [$\int_0^\pi \ln\sin x dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547663/solving-the-integral-int-0-pi-log-sin-x-mathrm-dx?noredirect=1)

Comment: May I know how did you get 2I in step 2?

Comment: Please, see the edit. @I_am_Math_Student

Comment: How did you get $\int_0^1 \ln(\Gamma(x)) dx = \int_0^1 \ln(\Gamma(1-x)) dx$?

Comment: @I_am_Math_Student $\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(a+b - x)dx$, proof is quite easy by substituion.

Comment: Those are some rather big hints.  ;-)

Comment: @MarkViola Yeah, $\sum_i \text{Hint }i = \text{Solution}$ but maybe the reader gets enough from some of them and will proceed by themselves :-)

Comment: A hint could be a comment, but a “rather big hint” should actually answer the question as an answer.

Comment: Can anyone explain how is $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\log(\sin x\pi)dx = \frac{1}{2π} \int_0^π\log(\sin x) dx$? I got stucked on this step with reference an answer on the question whose duplicate my question has marked been.

Comment: @VIVID can you explain me please?

Comment: @I_am_Math_Student take $t = x\pi$ then $dx = \frac{dt}{\pi}$ and $t \in [0,\pi]$ when $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Last thing, how is $\frac12 \ln(π) + \frac12 \ln(2) = \ln(\sqrt{2π})$?

Comment: @VIVID ........

Comment: @I_am_Math_Student $a\ln b = \ln b^a$ and $\ln a + \ln b = \ln ab$.