# A definite integral containing arctan (x)

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a university student and today I face to a definite integral containing arctan(x). I can't solve it. As follow:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2 \arctan^2 (x) + \tan(x)}{1+x^2} \, dx.$$

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Following $\large\tt @Lucian$ comment:
\begin{align}
&2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}x^{2}\tan^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x
=
-2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}x^{2}\,\dd x + 2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}x^{2}\sec^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi^{3} \over 96} + 2\pars{\pi \over 4}^{2}\tan\pars{\pi \over 4}
-4\int_{0}^{\pi/4}x\tan\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi^{3} \over 96} + {\pi^{2} \over 8}
-4\,{\pi \over 4}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{\pi \over 4}}
+4\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi^{3} \over 96} + {\pi^{2} \over 8}
+ {\pi \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2} +
4\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
\end{align}

Comment: $$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{4}} \ln (\cos (x)) \, dx = -\frac{1}{2}Catalan
$$
Is this right?

Comment: No, $\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\cos(x))\; dx = \dfrac{1}{2} \text{Catalan} - \dfrac{\pi}{4} \ln(2)$.

Comment: Sign errors in last two terms of the third line.

Comment: Oh，Thanks for your help~ I will try to do it again by myself~and wolfram tell me what is Catalan.
Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

One term is obvious from symmetry.  The other is not elementary: Maple gets

$$ \dfrac{\pi^2}{8} - \dfrac{\pi^3}{96} + \dfrac{\pi}{2} \ln(2) - 2 \;\text{Catalan}$$

Comment: It can be rewritten as $\displaystyle2\int_0^\frac\pi4x^2\tan^2x\,dx$.

Comment: True, but still not elementary.

Comment: ...then we use the fact that $\tan'x=\tan^2x+1$...

Comment: @Lucian. Could you go on ? Thanks

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: ...then we use integration by parts...

Comment: @Lucian. I picked this one but I am really looking for the full result. I found the antiderivative but it is so awful ! At the same time, the result of the integral is so beautiful ! Thanks for helping. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: See **Felix Marin**’s answer on this thread, and then use an approach similar to [Rob John’s](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300061/a-log-improper-integral/300319#300319) to compute the value of the *definite* integral of $\ln\cos x$ between $0$ and $\dfrac\pi4$.

Answer (score 0):

We can write $$\frac{x^2 \arctan^2 (x) + \tan(x)}{1+x^2}= \frac{x^2 \arctan^2 (x)}{1+x^2}+\frac{\tan(x)}{1+x^2} $$
Let $f(x)=\frac{x^2 \arctan^2 (x)}{1+x^2} \quad g(x)=\frac{\tan(x)}{1+x^2}$

$f(x)$ is an even function because $f(x)=f(-x)$, $g(x)$ is odd. The domain of the integral is symmetric, so we have $$\int_{-1}^{1} g(x) dx=0$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)dx   =  2\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$$

The whole integral is reduced to the solution of $$2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2 \arctan^2 (x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: Now notice that $\arctan'x=\dfrac1{1+x^2}$, and use substitution... Then read my comments on **Robert Israel**’s answer, and see **Felix Marin**’s response... :-)

Comment: Ok, I did the easy part. I'm sorry, what does it mean "Catalan"?

Comment: @twinprime:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant