# Find the closed form of $\int_0^{\large \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^{2n}\cdot\log{{\sin{x}}}}{\sin^{2n}{x}}dx, \space n\ge 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I was thinking of the generalization of the problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231055/how-to-solve-int-0-frac-pi2-fracx2-cdot-log-sin-x-sin2-xdx-using/1231089#1231089), that is

$$\int_0^{\large \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^{2n}\cdot\log{{\sin{x}}}}{\sin^{2n}{x}}dx, \space n\ge 1$$
Maybe you recommend me some tools?

Comment: Long time no see !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah, true. I'm pretty often in chat. :-)

Comment: My first impulse it to try to find a general formula for
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\left(\log^{k}(\sin{x})\right)
\end{equation*}
for $1 \leq k \leq 2n$, and then try to find a linear combination of such terms that adds to the integrand under consideration.